# problem with terminating the running program

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, window

i am making a wpf application in which there is a main window. normally when i close the main window the program used to terminate automatically but now it doesn't. altough the window is closed the program still seems to be running in visual studio. how can i fix this simple problem?

Comment: Just a suggestion: when debugging, click "Break All" (or Ctrl+Alt+Break) after closing the window. It will give you a hint about what is blocking the app from terminating.

Comment: i found and removed a breakpoint from the screen that you suggested but it didn't work. it still can not terminate itself

Comment: are you sure you don't have any event running in form_closing ?

Comment: When you click "Break all" as MainMa suggested, what code is executing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of [ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) on [Application.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current.aspx).  You may have it set to OnExplicitShutdown, in which case it's waiting for you to call [Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx).  The default is OnLastWindowClose, but you may have changed it in App.xaml or at runtime.

If not, then you still have a window open.  You can look at [Application.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) to find open windows and try to find why they haven't closed.